# How to control randomness for unit testing purposes in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'd like to inject a `RandomNumberGenerator` to my class in order to write unit tests. However, it seems that the methods that receive a random number generator only work with concrete types.

Which means that

```
var rng: RandomNumberGenerator = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
Bool.random(using: &rng)
```

does not compile, with the error:

> In argument type `inout RandomNumberGenerator`, `RandomNumberGenerator` does not conform to expected type `RandomNumberGenerator`

but

```
var rng = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
Bool.random(using: &rng)
```

does.

The trouble with that is that I'd like to use the default random number generator when running my app, and use a custom random number generator that i control for testing.  What is the general approach to controlling randomness in order to make testable code in Swift?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the exact error you got during compilation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/43408193#43408193), I used the "Build a type eraser" answer

```
    struct AnyRandomNumberGenerator: RandomNumberGenerator {
       private var generator: RandomNumberGenerator

       init(_ generator: RandomNumberGenerator) {
           self.generator = generator
       }

       mutating func next() -> UInt64 {
           return self.generator.next()
       }


       public mutating func next<T>() -> T where T : FixedWidthInteger, T : UnsignedInteger {
        return self.generator.next()
       }


       public mutating func next<T>(upperBound: T) -> T where T : FixedWidthInteger, T : UnsignedInteger {
            return self.generator.next(upperBound: upperBound)
      }

}
```

then it can be used like this

```
    var randomNumberGenerator: RandomNumberGenerator = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
    var random = AnyRandomNumberGenerator(randomNumberGenerator)
    UInt8.random(in: .min ... .max, using: &random)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has this problem in the future. I ended up writing my own `RandomNumberGenerator` that used a `SystemRandomNumberGenerator` in production and returns test values (if required) in debug mode. I don't know if this is the best way to go about it.

```
class TestableRNG: RandomNumberGenerator {
    private var rng = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
    private var testValue: UInt64?

    init() {
        self.testValue = nil
    }

    /**
     * - warning: Should only be used for testing purposes
     */
    init(valueForTesting: UInt64) {
        #if DEBUG
        self.testValue = valueForTesting
        #else
        self.testValue = nil
        #endif
    }


    func set(testValue: UInt64) {
        #if DEBUG
        self.testValue = testValue
        #endif
    }

    func next() -> UInt64 {
        #if DEBUG
        if let testValue = testValue {
            return testValue
        } else {
            return rng.next()
        }
        #else
        return rng.next()
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the root cause is fixable, I just don't know how. But until then, I suggest you update this code to use a seeded random number generator, (or trivially, just `(0...).makeIterator()`). Constant values could bring out pathological behaviour from code that expects uniform random values, e.g. for spreading values out in a data structure.